# Converting Spotify Link (or any music streaming service link) to another streaming service link (ex. Apple Music, Amazon, Tidal, SoundCloud, Youtube)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spotify, apple-music

I have been trying to figure out how to convert a music streaming service link to all the other ones that are given. In the pool, I have Spotify, Apple Music, Amazon, YouTube, SoundCloud, Tidal, and YouTube Music. The user would input a link to a song from any streaming service (ex. https://open.spotify.com/track/4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks?si=8f988d76f78941a6) and then the algorithm would spit out all the other links to the exact same song on the other platforms I listed above. This would be the exact same process and outcome similar to [SongWhip](https://songwhip.com/). I have been trying to figure out how to implement this with ReactJS. Please help if you can! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [Songlink's public API](https://www.notion.so/API-d0ebe08a5e304a55928405eb682f6741). It should do exactly what you're looking for, and includes all the major streaming services you mentioned.

Using the example song in your question, you would submit a GET request:

```
curl -X GET "https://api.song.link/v1-alpha.1/links?url=open.spotify.com%2Ftrack%2F4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks%3Fsi%3D8f988d76f78941a6"
```

And Songlink will return a json file with all the matching links in other streaming platforms (if they exist):

```
{
  "entityUniqueId": "SPOTIFY_SONG::4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks",
  "userCountry": "US",
  "pageUrl": "https://song.link/s/4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks",
  "entitiesByUniqueId": {
    "DEEZER_SONG::1275807472": {
      "id": "1275807472",
      "type": "song",
      "title": "Inhaled",
      "artistName": "Ahmad Anonimis",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/48acc171cd7310d10047e6066d136586/500x500-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "thumbnailWidth": 500,
      "thumbnailHeight": 500,
      "apiProvider": "deezer",
      "platforms": [
        "deezer"
      ]
    },
    "NAPSTER_SONG::tra.566238115": {
      "id": "tra.566238115",
      "type": "song",
      "title": "Inhaled",
      "artistName": "Ahmad Anonimis",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://direct.rhapsody.com/imageserver/images/alb.566238114/385x385.jpeg",
      "thumbnailWidth": 385,
      "thumbnailHeight": 385,
      "apiProvider": "napster",
      "platforms": [
        "napster"
      ]
    },
    "SOUNDCLOUD_SONG::1020531370": {
      "id": "1020531370",
      "type": "song",
      "title": "Inhaled (Prod. by Powers Pleasant)",
      "artistName": "Ahmad Anonimis",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-Mt2vlaVXZXzAosyy-1w1BOA-t500x500.jpg",
      "thumbnailWidth": 500,
      "thumbnailHeight": 500,
      "apiProvider": "soundcloud",
      "platforms": [
        "soundcloud"
      ]
    },
    "SPOTIFY_SONG::4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks": {
      "id": "4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks",
      "type": "song",
      "title": "Inhaled",
      "artistName": "Ahmad Anonimis",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2733ec2a571fa840e8a0a449107",
      "thumbnailWidth": 640,
      "thumbnailHeight": 640,
      "apiProvider": "spotify",
      "platforms": [
        "spotify"
      ]
    },
    "TIDAL_SONG::177197054": {
      "id": "177197054",
      "type": "song",
      "title": "Inhaled",
      "artistName": "Ahmad Anonimis",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://resources.tidal.com/images/2fb4cbe7/b022/408e/b8d1/79a8bf7eefb5/640x640.jpg",
      "thumbnailWidth": 640,
      "thumbnailHeight": 640,
      "apiProvider": "tidal",
      "platforms": [
        "tidal"
      ]
    },
    "YOUTUBE_VIDEO::3p4RJHoosg8": {
      "id": "3p4RJHoosg8",
      "type": "song",
      "title": "Ahmad Anonimis - Inhaled (Official Music Video)",
      "artistName": "Ahmad Anonimis",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3p4RJHoosg8/hqdefault.jpg",
      "thumbnailWidth": 480,
      "thumbnailHeight": 360,
      "apiProvider": "youtube",
      "platforms": [
        "youtube",
        "youtubeMusic"
      ]
    }
  },
  "linksByPlatform": {
    "deezer": {
      "country": "US",
      "url": "https://www.deezer.com/track/1275807472",
      "entityUniqueId": "DEEZER_SONG::1275807472"
    },
    "napster": {
      "country": "US",
      "url": "https://napster.com/track/tra.566238115",
      "entityUniqueId": "NAPSTER_SONG::tra.566238115"
    },
    "soundcloud": {
      "country": "US",
      "url": "https://soundcloud.com/ahmadanonimis-official/inhaled-prod-by-powers-pleasant",
      "entityUniqueId": "SOUNDCLOUD_SONG::1020531370"
    },
    "spotify": {
      "country": "US",
      "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks",
      "nativeAppUriDesktop": "spotify:track:4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks",
      "entityUniqueId": "SPOTIFY_SONG::4zfjkqJRJghGXUIq3Cosks"
    },
    "tidal": {
      "country": "US",
      "url": "https://listen.tidal.com/track/177197054",
      "entityUniqueId": "TIDAL_SONG::177197054"
    },
    "youtube": {
      "country": "US",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3p4RJHoosg8",
      "entityUniqueId": "YOUTUBE_VIDEO::3p4RJHoosg8"
    },
    "youtubeMusic": {
      "country": "US",
      "url": "https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=3p4RJHoosg8",
      "entityUniqueId": "YOUTUBE_VIDEO::3p4RJHoosg8"
    }
  }
}
```

This works for both songs and albums.